# Dynamically adding some <span> </ span>, the contents out of the container

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I should add "n" `<span> </ span>` (to display "n" flaticon-icons) to a div (my page is .php)

This is the ***div***

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="div_icone"></div>
```

This is ***div_icon*** css class

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .div_icone {
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 200px;
    }

}
```

This is ***icona_ambiente_lista*** css class

```
.icona_ambiente_lista,{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Flaticon;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

This is the code that works, as well as in the image below

```
<div style="width: 100%;" class="div_icone">

    <span class="flaticon-black210 icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    <span class="flaticon-ascendant6 icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    <span class="flaticon-baby67 icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    <span class="flaticon-bedroom2 icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    <span class="flaticon-bicycle12 icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    <span class="flaticon-apple icona_ambiente_lista" style="margin:9px"></span>
    .....                       

 </div>
```

[image]

seen that the icons are many, I wanted to add more quickly (via a loop) , and i try this

```
<?php

    $icona = ["black210","ascendant6","baby67","bedroom2","bicycle12","apple","business56","business57","business59","car80","car95","career","clapperboard","clock46","close13","cogs3","dining8","dwelling1","eco5","electronic55","facebook30","family20","family4","film51","fire14","flatscreen","home63","illness","lamp14","laptop44","man204","man77","motorcycle10","personal5","phone16","phone25","plate7","queen9","scooter7","screwdriver3","stair","student13","students3","studio","text87","toolbox3","traffic17","users6","waterdrop1"];

    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($icona) ; $i++){
        echo "<span class='flaticon-".$icona[$i]." icona_ambiente_lista' style='margin:9px'></span>";
    }

?>
```

or

```
<script>

    var icona = ["black210","ascendant6","baby67","bedroom2","bicycle12","apple","business56","business57","business59","car80","car95","career","clapperboard","clock46","close13","cogs3","dining8","dwelling1","eco5","electronic55","facebook30","family20","family4","film51","fire14","flatscreen","home63","illness","lamp14","laptop44","man204","man77","motorcycle10","personal5","phone16","phone25","plate7","queen9","scooter7","screwdriver3","stair","student13","students3","studio","text87","toolbox3","traffic17","users6","waterdrop1"];

    for(var i = 0 ; i < icona.length ; i++){
        $(".div_icone").append( "<span class='flaticon-"+icona[i]+" icona_ambiente_lista' style='margin:9px'></span>" );
    }

</script>
```

but the result is this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icons were wrapped because you initially had new line characters at the end of each line. So, in order to get the same result, add a space or a new line character in the loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($icona); $i++) {
    // --------------------v
    echo "<span ...></span> ";  // or "\r\n", or PHP_EOL
}
```